# Difference between programming extension and API

Tags: php, api

For example, PHP has mysqli and PDO functions under the name of "Database extensions". Can it also be called "Database APIs"?
This is all about terminology, i researched and am thinking that extension and api is the same thing but there is no proof that i found, so i need to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Database extensions are like Mysql driver and Postgres Driver, there are .dll or .so files needed for your PHP to be connected for those database.

1. [Mysqli reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)
2. [PDO Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)
3. [PHP extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.state.php)

PHP Database API are any functions, method, classes and etc that you can use to manipulate data(DML), and define data (DDL) 
[DML and DLL Reference](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php)

ex. [mysqli function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: so extensions include APIs?